Error installing spl-token-cli via cargo on WSL

Problem:
I receive the error message: could not compile solana-accounts-db (lib)
For more descriptive error details pls refer the screenshot attached
Desired Outcome:
My goal is to successfully install spl-token-cli for use within my WSL environment.
Additional Information:
Operating System: Windows (version not specified)
WSL Distribution:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Cargo Version: cargo 1.75.0
Rust Version: rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)

Steps to Reproduce:
Open a terminal window within your WSL environment.
Run the command: cargo install spl-token-cli

Expected Behavior:
The spl-token-cli should be successfully installed and available for use

You need to upgrade your local Rust to 1.76, or better, the same version used by the Solana 2.0 release, which is 1.78: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/v2.0/rust-toolchain.toml
rustup toolchain install 1.78.0

After that, you should be able to build no problem.
